# Weird undefined control sequence with \nextgroupplot (solved with "globalization")?

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} %\widthof

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\def\firstRowA{0}
\def\lastRowA{5}

\def\firstRowB{45}
\def\lastRowB{80}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my fancy plots,
    group size=2 by 1,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
    %xticklabels at=edge bottom,
    %vertical sep=0pt,
    horizontal sep=0pt,
  },
  %width=8.5cm,
  height=6cm,
  ymin=-6, ymax=6,
  domain=0:80,
]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xminA}{\firstRowA+0.5} %
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmaxA}{\lastRowA+0.5} %
\typeout{xminA \xminA, xmaxA \xmaxA}

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=\xminA,xmax=\xmaxA,
  xtick={0,5,10},
  axis y line=left,
  %axis x discontinuity=parallel, % disc. is at start, so avoid for first
  axis x line=bottom,
  x axis line style=-, % switch off the axis arrow tips,
  %width=4.5cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {x*0};
\addplot {x*0+1};


\pgfmathsetmacro{\xminB}{\firstRowB+0.5} %
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmaxB}{\lastRowB+0.5} %
\typeout{xminB \xminB, xmaxB \xmaxB}

\nextgroupplot[
%   xmin=45.5,xmax=80.5, % this works fine
  xmin=\xminB,xmax=\xmaxB,
  axis y line=none,
  xtick={60,80},
  axis x discontinuity=parallel,
  axis x line=bottom,
  %width=2.0cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {0*x};
\addplot {2+0*x};

\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you compile it as-is, it will fail with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@loc@TMPa ->\xminB 

l.73 ]
```

... which is weird, because the `\typeout` just before that:

```
xminA 0.5, xmaxA 5.5
xminB 45.5, xmaxB 80.5
```

... confirms that, indeed, the `\xminB` macro is defined and does have a value?

If numbers are entered directly (that is, `xmin=45.5,xmax=80.5,`) - then the MWE compiles fine, and results with the expected rendering:

[image: test02.png]

Why does this happen - and how can I use a macro for `xmin` in this position?

---

**EDIT**: just solved the problem - seems that I need to "globalize" the second pair of macros: just add this in the code above:

```
...
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xminB}{\firstRowB+0.5} %
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmaxB}{\lastRowB+0.5} %
\typeout{xminB \xminB, xmaxB \xmaxB}

% globalize - with expand!
\xdef\xminB{\xminB} % add redefinition
\xdef\xmaxB{\xmaxB} % add redefinition

\nextgroupplot[
...
```

... then the MWE compiles fine. But I'm still puzzled - how come I do *not* have to "globalize" the macro pair for the first `\nextgroupplot`; and yet I *must* "globalize" the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing the setting of `\xmaxB` and `\xminB` in a group.

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{\firstRowB+0.5}\global\let\xminB\temp
\pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{\lastRowB+0.5}\global\let\xmaxB\temp
```

will make the definition of the macros transcend the group boundary.

Comment: Thanks for that, @egreg - wasn't aware that there was a group boundary here; cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to move the definitions of `\xminB`/`\xmaxB` to just after the definitions of `\xminA`/`\xmaxA`, though I cannot say exactly why. I assume `\nextgroupplot` creates a group, so that the definition becomes local to the first groupplot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} %\widthof

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\def\firstRowA{0}
\def\lastRowA{5}

\def\firstRowB{45}
\def\lastRowB{80}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my fancy plots,
    group size=2 by 1,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
    %xticklabels at=edge bottom,
    %vertical sep=0pt,
    horizontal sep=0pt,
  },
  %width=8.5cm,
  height=6cm,
  ymin=-6, ymax=6,
  domain=0:80,
]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xminA}{\firstRowA+0.5} %
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmaxA}{\lastRowA+0.5} %
\typeout{xminA \xminA, xmaxA \xmaxA}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xminB}{\firstRowB+0.5} %
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmaxB}{\lastRowB+0.5} %
\typeout{xminB \xminB, xmaxB \xmaxB}

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=\xminA,xmax=\xmaxA,
  xtick={0,5,10},
  axis y line=left,
  %axis x discontinuity=parallel, % disc. is at start, so avoid for first
  axis x line=bottom,
  x axis line style=-, % switch off the axis arrow tips,
  %width=4.5cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {x*0};
\addplot {x*0+1};




\nextgroupplot[
%   xmin=45.5,xmax=80.5, % this works fine
  xmin=\xminB,xmax=\xmaxB,
  axis y line=none,
  xtick={60,80},
  axis x discontinuity=parallel,
  axis x line=bottom,
  %width=2.0cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {0*x};
\addplot {2+0*x};

\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @TorbjørnT. - I have just realized that I can also use a global redefinition to fix that problem (see OP edit), so the question is now a bit more towards why does this happen. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau As I say (guess), if `\nextgroupplot` starts a new group, then the `\xminA` will be defined before and outside the first groupplot. As it is defined outside the group, it is available inside it. But `\xminB` is *defined inside* the group, so it is not available outside.